# Implementar un Infinite Scroll utilizando el next_url y prev_url en ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Mi duda es si es posible crear un scroll infinito de una api que ya te brinda la siguiente url de la siguiente pagina de datos sin necesidad de usar un contador para avanzar o retroceder de pagina.
Ejemplo, unir mi acción de obtenerPagAccion junto con siguentePagAccion para obtener el scroll infinito, tipo ejemplo crear una acción que contenga [...obtenerPagAccion, ...siguentePagAccion]
Si alguien tiene documentación sobre eso, eternamente agradecido. :)

```
export const obtenerPagAccion = () => async dispatch => {
/* if (localStorage.getItem('offset=0')) {
    dispatch({
        type: 'OBTENER_ARTE_EXITO',
        payload: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('offset=0')),
    });
    return;
} */
try {
    const res = await axios.get(
        `https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks?page=0&limit=15`
    );
    dispatch({
        type: 'OBTENER_ARTE_EXITO',
        payload: res.data,
    });
    /* localStorage.setItem('offset=0', JSON.stringify(res.data)); */
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
} };

export const siguentePagAccion = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
const { next_url } = getState().artes.pagination;

if (localStorage.getItem(next_url)) {
    dispatch({
        type: 'SIGUIENTE_ARTE_EXITO',
        payload: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(next_url)),
    });
    return;
}
try {
    const res = await axios.get(next_url);
    dispatch({
        type: 'SIGUIENTE_ARTE_EXITO',
        payload: res.data,
    });
    localStorage.setItem(next_url, JSON.stringify(res.data));
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
} };
```

Comment: lo mismo que hacen las redes sociales para mostrarte contenido sin descanso y sigas conectado, si muchas redes sociales lo usan, debe de haber documentación al alcance, una búsqueda rápida en Google ayuda :D.

Comment: Si lo se, pero el problema es que toda la documentación que he visto gira en torno a un contador, y no a la paginación de la api, aun me estoy plantando si realmente se puede hacer con la paginación por que no he encontrado nada ;(

Comment: Hoo... valla!, no estoy muy metido en temas de web (en especial forntend) por lo que no puedo decirte si existe o no forma de hacerlo como quieres. Lo siento por no poder ayudar :/

Comment: Yo creo que se podría implementar usando [Scroll event throttling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) y un ciclo, donde se pasaría el incremento del parámetro `page` mas su correspondiente llamada API async, dependiendo del estado (posición) en que se encuentra el scroll dentro del documento.